# Refermentation with fruits and sugar

Tags: fermentation, yeast, fruit

I recently brewed a wheat beer that is now in primary fermentation. 
I planned on using yuzu juice after primary to give a special taste.

Also, after some thought I wanted to add a little ABV (from 3.6 to around 4%) to the beer because for now I think it is too light.

My question is :

- Do you think I can add some blond DME (around 400g) at the same time as the fruit juice (yuzu) when I transfert my wort to a second carboy? (my wort is 21L)
- For sure I will have a refermentation, but will there be enough yeast left to conduct it? (my pitch rate for primary was 0.75)
- Will I have enough yeast after some weeks when priming for bottling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the (DME) gravity correction ASAP in primary.

As far as the yuzu juice. It should list the carbohydrates amount on the label and may contribute to the priming sugars. *Most important: make sure it doesn't have preservatives, most preservatives are fermentation inhibitors.*

For example Sam Adams Yuzu Reserve. Says "with yuzu juice added" not fermented. Meaning it's added after fermentation. Usually when it's on its way to the bright tank for carbonation.

Edit: I don't think bottle conditioning will be an option for you. Yuzu does seem to have preservatives. While these preservatives usually don't kill yeast, they just inhibit growth, your bottles will be left to condition in a less than ideal environment.

Comment: so you think it will be impossible to conduct bottling fermentation after the adding of 300 ml of yuzu ? even if I add priming sugar ?

Comment: In that case I could maybe use yuzu powder no? https://www.amazon.com/powder-Citrus-Japan-cooking-spice/dp/B00JX5H0N8

Comment: Depends on the type of preservatives. If it's just an inhibitor, existing healthy yeast will carbonate the bottles if there's enough. But cell division will be halted.

Comment: @JeanMi why not just use real fruit or zest?

Comment: Real fruit is quite hard to find where i live :/ I do have zest and i have used some already for 5min in boiling,

Comment: I guess i'll first add my DME and then when the DME is fermented, add my yuzu, wait more and then check if there is enough yeast before bottling, if not then i just toss some dry ones to finish the work. sounds right ? thx anyway :)

Comment: @JeanMi yeah give it a shot. If it doesn't work there's other options to force carb for cheap. Such as using soda bottles and a co2 cartridge dispensor cap.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are still in primary fermentation (I suppose that fermentation is still going) on, 2g/100 ml (calculated from your current information) of wort should absolutely be no problem in your secondary fermentation, even with the yuzu juice.

For adding the DME, you will have to cook it up first in some extra water, so if you want to increase your ABV, you will have to take into account your current volume, the amount of water needed to dissolve the DME and the amount of yuzu juice to calculate the correct amount of DME needed.

Comment: i don't know what is the maximum DME concentration that i can have in water, i was planning 400g of DME in 0.5L of water, sounds possible ? also my yuzu juice will be around 300ml, anyway thx :)

Comment: One could always use LME as being liquid it can be easier to dissolve.